# VBA Combine data

Tags: excel, vba

Lets say I have this sample data (image below). What I would like to do is if funding type is A then combine the data using the V Number and sum up Open Base Other and Total Columns.

[image: Sample Data]

I have this code but it works with 2 columns and can't figure out a way to combine all columns mentioned above. I also would like to exclude some items from combining, is that doable?

```
Sub CombineRows()
'Updateby Extendoffice
Dim WorkRng As Range
Dim Dic As Variant
Dim arr As Variant
On Error Resume Next
xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
arr = WorkRng.Value
For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
    Dic(arr(i, 1)) = Dic(arr(i, 1)) + arr(i, 2)
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
WorkRng.ClearContents
WorkRng.Range("A1").Resize(Dic.Count, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Dic.keys)
WorkRng.Range("B1").Resize(Dic.Count, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Dic.items)
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: A pivot table with a filter will do this.

Comment: What if lets say the name was BOB Smith instead of just Bob would you be able to combine it then?

Comment: You said your criteria was `V Number` and `Funding Type`  Based on those two items, a simple pivot table would work.  If you want to include fuzzy matching on a third column that will get quite intricate.